# Проверка содержимого zip архива

Tags: php, zip

Как проверить в отправленном через форму архиве zip, есть ли в корне файл `index.html` и если есть выполнить действие?

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое решение это попытаться банально распаковать архив в /tmp, используя exec('unzip /tmp/tmparchive.zip'), и далее проверить наличие файла в распакованном дереве.

При реализации учтите, что zip-архивы могут быть запаролены, и без пароля их содержимое проверить затруднительно.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы рекомендовал Вам использовать расширение для PHP Zip (обычно оно установлено по умолчанию или довольно просто ставится через PECL)

```
/**
 * Функция поиска файла/папки внутри архива Zip (работает и с запароленными архивами)
 * @param string $path_to_archive - полный путь до архива
 * @param string $find - что ищем, например index.html
 * @param boolean $is_dir - является ли искомое папкой
 * @return boolean|array - функция вернет false в случае ошибки или массив с детальной информацие по найденному элементу
 * @throws \Exception - в случае неведомой фигни будет выброшено исключение
 */
function find_in_zip_archive($path_to_archive, $find, $is_dir = false) {
    $zip = new \ZipArchive();
    $open_status = $zip->open($path_to_archive);
    if ($open_status === true) {

        if (mb_strlen($find, "UTF-8") > 0) {

            /*
             * Т.к. файлы и папаки в архиве имеют относительный "путь" (Прим. index.php, dir/dir/file, dir/dir/dir/), 
             * нам необходимо удалить первый слэш из переменной $find (ну, если он там есть)
             */
            if ($find[0] == "/") {
                $find = substr($find, 1);
            }

            /**
             * Чтобы найти папку, нужно чтобы $find заканчивался на / (Прим. dir/dir/dir/)
             */
            if ($is_dir == true AND $find[mb_strlen($find, "UTF-8") - 1] != "/") {
                $find .="/";
            }
        } else {
            throw new \Exception("Вы не ввели имя файла/папки для поиска");
        }

        $finded_entity = false;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
            $one_file = $zip->statIndex($i);
            if (is_array($one_file) AND isset($one_file["name"])) {
                if ($find == $one_file["name"]) {
                    $finded_entity = $one_file;
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                throw new \Exception("При получении информации о файле/папке внутри архива возникла неизвестная ошибка");
            }
        }
        if ($zip->close() == true) {
            return $finded_entity;
        } else {
            throw new \Exception("При закрытии архива возникла неизвестная ошибка");
        }
    } else {
        throw new \Exception("Ошибка при открытии архива: (код: {$open_status})");
    }
}

try {
    // Проверим, что установлено расширение Zip
    if (extension_loaded("zip") === false) {
        throw new \Exception("Расширение ZIP не установлено");
    }


    if (is_array($_FILES) AND empty($_FILES) == false) {
        $path_to_zip_archive = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
        $file_in_archive = find_in_zip_archive($path_to_zip_archive, "index.html");
        //Если функция вернула массив, значит файл найден
        if (is_array($file_in_archive)) {
            //Делаем что-то
        } else {
            //Делаем еще что-то
        }
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```